# mock method expecting a list

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I have a method that expects a collection of strings and that I want to mock:

```
bool DoSomething(IEnumerable<string> myList) { ... }
```

I want to mock every call to that method having any collection with the following items: `["DLKM"]`, no matter if the type of the collection is an array or a list or whatever.

Therefor I created an argument-matcher using NSubstitute:

```
var modellarten = Arg.Is<IEnumerable<string>>(x => !new[] { "DLKM" }.Except(x).Any());
```

this matches any collection of strings that only contain the string `"DLKM"`.

This is my mock:

```
var mock = Substitute.For<IMyInterface>();
mock.DoSomething(modellarten).Returns(true);
```

However as soon as I mock multiple methods using the same arg-matcher, the call to `DoSomething` returns the default-value `false`:

```
var mock = Substitute.For<IMyInterface>();
mock.Init(modellarten).Returns(true);
mock.DoSomething(modellarten).Returns(true);
```

So I suppose it has to do with the closure within the matcher. But I don´t know how to mock both methods without repeating the code for `modellarten`:

```
var mock = Substitute.For<IMyInterface>();
mock.Init(Arg.Is<IEnumerable<string>>(x => !new[] { "DLKM" }.Except(x).Any())).Returns(true);
mock.DoSomething(Arg.Is<IEnumerable<string>>(x => !new[] { "DLKM" }.Except(x).Any())).Returns(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting the matcher into a single variable, just extract the code into a method you call on every mock:

```
IMyInterface MockInterface()
{
    var mock = Substitute.For<IMyInterface>();
    mock.Init(MatchCollection()).Returns(true);
    mock.DoSomething(MatchCollection()).Returns(true);
    return mock;
}
IEnumerable<string> MatchCollection() 
{
    return Arg.Is<IEnumerable<string>>(x => !new[] { "DLKM" }.Except(x).Any());
}
```

This will create a new matcher on every call instead of using a previously created one.